# what is the behavior of cname on apache/nginx

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, virtualhost, cname-record, apache2

Say I have a domain `fish.example.com` with an a record pointing to a http server running apache/nginx and with a vhost setup for that domain. I also create a CNAME from `cow.example.net` to `fish.example.com`

What domain ends up at my apache/nginx, and is this behavior configurable by apache/nginx?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what cnames are for, and your proposal around DNS is solid. You will need to have a virtual host defined for both cow.sample.net and fish.example.com, as both could potentially be used to access your site (unless you only intend for clients to connect using one of them).

This can be done like so within the virtual hosts configuration of apache / nginx:

```
<VirtualHost cow.sample.net>
    DocumentRoot "/www/site"
    ServerName cow.sample.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost fish.example.com>
    DocumentRoot "/www/site"
    ServerName fish.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: is their a way to rewrite/redirect with apache or nginx configuration?
maybe with a custom mod? 
I want to have the user enter cow.sample.net, but I want my app (php) to be aware of the fact of fish.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Whichever name gets entered into the browser address bar, gets sent by the browser to the server in the form of the `host` HTTP header, which is what your server inspects to properly serve its vhosts.